# eventlistener all in one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$something.on('mousedown touchstart mousemove', function(e){
   // everything do something
   if('mousedown') // do something

   if('touchstart') // do something

   if('mousemove') // do something
});
```

Is it possible to do something like that? Whats the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `switch` for [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/):

```
$something.on("mousedown touchstart mousemove", function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "mousedown":
            // do something
            break;

        case "touchstart":
            // do something
            break;

        case "mousemove":
            // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: cool, it'd be handy, I always separate all listener and make the script hell long

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is create a handler function with internal methods to match the events:

```
$('div').on('mouseenter click', evtHandler)

function  evtHandler(evt, el) {
    var _self=this, $el=$(this);

    var handler = {
        click: function() {
            $el.text('Div was clicked on')
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
            $el.css('background','#EAEAEA')
        }
    };
    handler[evt.type]();
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ufYKF/

Comment: handler[xxx](), whats that for? and what _self for? could you a bit explain more about handler?

Comment: context of `this` within `evtHandler` is the DOM node, since there is no anonymous function used in `on`. `_self` is simply a variable you can use for native javascript properties within `handler` such as `var id= _self.id`.

Comment: this approach allows splitting code up for larger applications.

Comment: Dom nodes are <html> <h1> <title> <p> something like that? are there any simple tutorial on writing handlers? I didn't write it b4.